# Failed using VBA and advanced filter to summarize data in one worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to summarize data in the first worksheet, so I used Advanced filter, but it seems that something went wrong with my code. I already wrote my criteria in worksheet1 `a2:a3`.

```vb
Sub loop_all_adfilter_NG_paste()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim ws_count As Integer
ws_count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
For i = 10 To 16
Worksheets("worksheet1").Select
    Worksheets(i).Range("A13:M1048").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy,_
    CriteriaRange:=Range("a2:a3"), 
    CopyToRange:=Range("C1").End(xlDown).Offset(1), Unique:= _
    False
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some typos in your code, so it doesn't compile.

See how I fully qualify the sheets and ranges objects

```
Public Sub loop_all_adfilter_NG_paste()
    
    ' Define and set a reference to the criteria sheet
    Dim criteriaSheet As Worksheet
    Set criteriaSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("worksheet1")
    
    ' Define and set the criteria data range
    Dim dataRange As Range
    Set dataRange = criteriaSheet.Range("A2:A3")
    
    ' Define the range's address to be filtered
    Dim filterAddress As String
    filterAddress = "A13:M1048"
    
    ' Define the filtered sheets index as a variant to store an array
    Dim sheetsIndex As Variant
    sheetsIndex = Array(10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16)
    
    Dim counter As Integer
    For counter = 0 To UBound(sheetsIndex)
        ' Filter the sheet
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetsIndex(counter)).Range(filterAddress).AdvancedFilter _
        Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CriteriaRange:=dataRange, _
        CopyToRange:=criteriaSheet.Range("C1").End(xlDown).Offset(1), Unique:=False
    Next counter
    
End Sub
```

Read the code's comments and adjust it to fit your needs

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example. criteriaSheet and CopyToRange must exist on the same sheet. You haven't specified sheets that correspond to the parent of the two ranges. Please specify where the range is on the sheet.

```
Sub setAdvancedFilter()
    Dim rngDB As Range
    Dim rngCri As Range
    Dim rngTo As Range
    
    Set rngDB = Sheet1.Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    Set rngCri = Sheet2.Range("a1:a2")
    Set rngTo = Sheet2.Range("a4:e4")
    
    Sheet2.Range("a1").Value = Sheet1.Range("a1").Value
    rngTo.Value = Sheet1.Range("a1:e1").Value
    
    rngDB.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, rngCri, rngTo
    
End Sub
```